# Compare in Database or Backend?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I need to import a csv file into my Postgresql database, however I need to compare whether the data in the file rows already exists in my database.
This comparison will be made using levenshtein distance.
If the line does not match, it must be inserted. If it matches, not insert.
I would like to know if it is better to make this comparison on the backend (my backend is nodejs) or create a temporary table and compare in the database?

Comment: "Better" from what perspective? Simplicity and ease? Performance and troughput? Something else? How big is the file?

Comment: @Bergi Both rs, Performance and troughput.. my csv file has 4000 lines and my database has little more 1 million lines.